# Fourier transform getting magnitude value in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, fft

I have the following code that use simple algorithm for fourier transform, but it not working like it should.

```
public int ft(int x, int y, int br, int a, int height, int width, int[][] pixelTemp, double c){
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    double avg;     
    double newCitra = 0;
    int temp;
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<width; j++){
            temp = pixelTemp[i][j];
            r = (temp>>16)&0xff;
            g = (temp>>8)&0xff;
            b = temp&0xff;
            avg = (r+g+b)/3;
            if (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width))))>0){
                if(-2*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width))>0){
                    newCitra = ((newCitra + (((double)avg/(double)(height*width)))*(sqrt(Math.pow((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width))))),2)+Math.pow((double)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width)))),2)))));
                } else {
                    newCitra = ((newCitra + (((double)avg/(double)(height*width)))*(sqrt(Math.pow((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width))))),2)-Math.pow((double)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width)))),2)))));
                }                    
            } else {
                if(-2*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width))>0){
                    newCitra = (newCitra + ((double)avg/(double)(height*width))*((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width)))))+(double)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width))))));
                } else {
                    newCitra = (newCitra + ((double)avg/(double)(height*width))*((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width)))))-(double)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width))))));
                }
            }
            /*System.out.println(newCitra);*/
        }
    }
    newCitra = (int) (Math.log(1+newCitra)*c);
    int j = 30;
    int i = 10;
    /*System.out.println(Math.abs(sqrt(Math.pow((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width))))),2)-Math.pow((double)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(360*(((double)(i*x)/(double)height)+((double)(j*y)/(double)width)))),2))));*/
    int p = (255<<24) | ((int)newCitra<<16) | ((int)newCitra<<8) | (int)newCitra;

    return p;
}
```

This is the following result:

[image]

Obviously I made some mistake here, but I couldn't figure it out, the value in sqrt root can be negative that will result NaN but I am following the fourier transform formula.

Comment: can you point to the formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you have misinterpreted the formulas. From another implementation I have

```
real +=  tempreal[row][t] * cos[col][t] - tempimag[row][t] * sin[col][t];
imag +=  tempreal[row][t] * sin [col][t] + tempimag[row][t] * cos[col][t];
```

So once you have the real and imaginary parts you do the square root

```
mag=Math.sqrt(real*real+imag*imag);
```

Also in the cosine/sine

```
cos[i][t]=Math.cos(2*Math.PI*t*i/n);
sin[i][t]=Math.sin(2*Math.PI*t*i/n);
```

I dont see a square rather a doubling.

--

I have updated your function as follows:

a) the real and imaginary parts need to be computed separately, there is no computation on the complex number
b) some rearrangements

It seems to work and if you try with the image shown here http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm the diagonal stripes you will get the diagonal as shown on that page.

```
public double ft(int x, int y, int br, int a, int height, int width, int[][] pixelTemp, double c){
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    double avg;     
    double newCitrar = 0, newCitrai = 0;
    int temp;
    double f=(double)1/(double)(height*width);
    for (int i=0; i<width; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<height; j++){
            temp = pixelTemp[i][j];
//            r = (temp>>16)&0xff;
//            g = (temp>>8)&0xff;
//            b = temp&0xff;
            avg = temp; // (r+g+b)/3;
        newCitrar = newCitrar + avg*Math.cos(2*Math.PI*(((double)(i*x)/(double)width)+((double)(j*y)/(double)height)));
        newCitrai=newCitrai+avg*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*(((double)(i*x)/(double)width)+((double)(j*y)/(double)height)));
      }
    }
    newCitrar *=f;
    newCitrai *=f;
    double newCitra=Math.sqrt(newCitrar*newCitrar+newCitrai*newCitrai);
    return newCitra;
}
```

On the display side I have the following:

```
  BufferedImage bim=null;
  try {
    bim=ImageIO.read(new File("str.gif"));
  }
  catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("error"); }
  int wc=bim.getWidth(), hc=bim.getHeight();
  BufferedImage b2=new BufferedImage(wc, hc, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

  int[] pix=bim.getRGB(0, 0, wc, hc, null, 0, wc);
  int[][] pix2=new int[wc][hc];
  double ri;
  for(i=0; i<wc; i++)
  for(j=0; j<hc; j++) {
    int rr=(pix[i+j*wc]&0x00ff0000)>>16, rg=(pix[i+j*wc]&0x0000ff00)>>8, rb=pix[i+j*wc]&0x000000ff;
    ri=0.2126*rr+0.7152*rg+0.0722*rb;
    pix2[i][j]=(int)ri;
  }
  double max=0;
  for(i=0; i<wc; i++)
  for(j=0; j<hc; j++) {
  if(i%10==0 && j%10==0) System.out.println(i+" "+j);
    double ki=ft(i, j, 0, 0, hc, wc, pix2, 1);
    if(ki>max) max=ki;
    b2.setRGB(i, j, (int)ki);
  }
  saveImageIO(b2, (time/1000)+"f-1");

  double cc=255./Math.log(1+max);
  System.out.println(max+" "+cc);
  for(i=0; i<wc; i++)
  for(j=0; j<hc; j++) {
    b2.setRGB(i, j, (int) (Math.log(1+(b2.getRGB(i, j)&0x00ffffff))*cc));
  }   

  saveImageIO(b2, (time/1000)+"f-2");
```

Comment: In `avg = (r+g+b)/3;`, `avg` is declared as a `double`, but assigned the result of `int` calculations, which will remove any fractional part.

Comment: and?? are the formulas corect?? what are you talking about? 3 instead of 3.3??  you are talking  bogus!! @Lew Bloch

Comment: @LewBloch your comment is about Asker's own code. Did you type this in the wrong place?

Comment: @Lew Bloch i use avg as double because i want a more spesific value so the result more accurate when i cast it, is it wrong do it that way? or is there more better way?

Comment: @gpasch thanks for your repply, i really appreciate it, i try to implement your code on mine and now there is no more NaN result but the result is different from what i expected and i also checked it in another program, Gwyddion, what is the variable t mean here i take it as x and y, the code goes like this: `sin = Math.sin(2*Math.PI*x*i/height); cos = Math.cos(2*Math.PI*y*j/width);`

Comment: you are right in this - do you have the expected fourier spectrum/magnitude? can you post the expected image?

Comment: In the original code, yes, we are not getting double precision in that calculation, we are gettting integer precision. The calculation `avg = (r + g + b) / 3;` has variables `r`, `g`, and `b` that are all `int` variables, as is the literal `3`. That means that the addition and division are carried out by `int` values, with no fractional part of course. The result of the division is truncated to `int`. Then it is assigned to a `double`, but the fractional part of the division was lost.